# Intent to install APK in Android

Tags: android, installation, apk

I Try to install apk from file in android but the  output is:

> There is a Problem Parsing the Package

If i try with the android explorer the APK install.

My code:

```
  public void instalarPath() {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/downloadedfile.apk");
       mensaje(file.getName());//File existis
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.andriod.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mostrarcasoderrror(e.toString(), e.toString());
    }
}
```

The manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Shows:

> ANDROID.CONTENTE ACTIVIY NOTFOUND EXCEPTION TO HANDLE INTENTE {ACT=android.intent.action.view dat=file:///mounted/donwloadedfile.apk type=application/}

Comment: Where does `llegada` point to? Also note that you have a typo in your MIME type, and that you cannot hold the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission unless your app is signed by the firmware's signing key.

Comment: Ok , let me remove INSTALL PACKAGES and show llegada

Answer (score 2):

```
mensaje(file.getName());//File existis
```

No, that file does not exist.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/downloadedfile.apk");
```

That is not a valid path on any Android device manufactured in human history. `getExternalStorageState()` will return a value like `unmountable`, not some filesystem directory.

Comment: If i change Environment.getExternalStorageState() to "/sdcard/" ?

Comment: @DanielORTIZ: I would recommend something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/downloadedfile.apk"
```

Is not doing what you are assuming it is doing, as @CommonsWare has mentioned.

Assuming you have said file in the device storage, you want to use: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` or even `getExternalCacheDir()` if your download routine supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using `MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();`

```
  File file = new File(llegada);
        mensaje(Uri.fromFile(file).getEncodedPath());//File existis
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       // File file = new File(path);

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext=file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

        startActivity(intent);
```